# Image size needed to cover screen in all devices in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview

I want to put an image on background of the sign up view. It needs to fill all screen density like iPhone 4,5,6,6S and iPAD. I will support portrait only.

What I have to do?

1. Should I make a `1920X1080` (iPhone 6s Plus) and put that in background view and then set auto layout to cover full screen.
2. Should I make `ImageName@2x` with size of `640X960`, `ImageName-667h@2x` `1334X750` iPhone 6, `ImageName-736h@3x` `1920X1080` iPhone 6Plus, `ImageName-568h@2x` `640X1136` for iPhone 5?

Comment: I think you should do this if you don't want your image will be distorty

Comment: @CongTran which one should i use first or second?

Comment: Well I think you should try 1st case first, then run it in all simulators for review. If you feel fine, just keep it, if not, you have to do in 2st case. Because in both of them, you still have to make an 1920X1080 image for it.

Comment: And remember to ask your designer to review it also (in 1st case) :D, If they think it's fine, you won't have to create another images for another screens

Comment: you should do like this. if background have not gradient than ask you designer to develop one pdf vector image. other wise you have to add images for according to apple guideline for different iOS Devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stick to the 2nd option (also consider using an asset catalog for that purpose instead of a set of images) because:

- It will let the [app package thinning](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html) feature to work.
- It will help you avoid image distortion caused by image resizing.
- It will reduce CPU rendering (which is implied by image re-scaling).

I hope this helps you make a wise choice. Cheers.